# Mocha Chai assert looks like ignored

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, assert, chai

I have this little code:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
describe('simple check', function() {
  it('this one shows output', function() {
    expect(1).to.equal(1);
  });
});


var assert = require('chai').assert;
assert(1 === 1, 'this one looks like ignored');
```

and so I get

> $ mocha test
>
> simple check
>       ✓ this one shows output
>
> 1 passing (5ms)

Why the second test is ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocha does not show which assertions have been run, it just shows which tests have been run. In this case you have only one test which is `this one shows output`.

So if you don't put any assertion, it still outputs the same thing:

```
describe('simple check', function() {
  it('this one shows output', function() {
  });
});
```

Also if there's any error in any assertion in anywhere in the file, it will show it. So if you put `assert(1 === 2, 'one should be two');` it will throw an error and show it to you.